# How to launch a process inside a minimal linux kernel environment?

Tags: c, linux, bash, linux-kernel, qemu

Is it possible to run a generic C program on top of the bare linux kernel?

I am using a virtualized linux minimal system with Qemu, where I load my custom kernel and a root filesystem, but I apparently can't run my user-space hello world program.

EDIT 1: I have updated the question to be more detailed. Here are the steps I have followed:

1] I have compiled the hello_world program with the following command, on my host machine:

```
gcc hello_world.c -o hello_world
```

The source code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

By running the program on my host machine, it works fine.
I have checked as @nexus suggested the libraries against which the program is built, and are the following:

```
    $ ldd hello_world
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc0dfc8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007efd90658000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055a57447f000)
```

2] I have build the root filesystem by executing buildroot, which comes by default from [Ciro Santilli's linux-kernel-module-cheat](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat). I have compiled the linux kernel and got its corresponding bzImage

3] I have mounted the root filesystem and copied my compiled program inside of it, as follows:

```
sudo mount -t ext2 rootfs.ext2 /home/andreww/Desktop/mountfile/
sudo cp hello_world /home/andreww/Desktop/mountfile/
sudo umount /home/andreww/Desktop/mountfile/
```

This feels wrong, I did it because I haven't found a way to compile the C program directly inside the Guest Machine.
On the guest machine I don't have gcc, indeed if I try to call it I get:

```
 # -sh: gcc: not found
```

4] I have started the emulated system with the command

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -M pc \
    -append 'root=/dev/vda $extra_append' \
    -drive file=${images_dir}/rootfs.ext2,if=virtio,format=raw \
    -kernel ${images_dir}/bzImage \
    -m 256M \
    -net nic,model=virtio \
    -net user \
    -enable-kvm \
    -cpu host \
    -smp threads=4
```

Which I have taken from [Ciro Santilli's linux-kernel-module-cheat](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat). 
The rootfs.ext2 is the root filesystem which the system is started against, and the bzImage is the kernel image I am going to start the guest machine with.

5] The guest machine is emulated within a shell. This is what I expected since I am virtualizing only the bare kernel and not a whole operating system image.

I am displayed the buildroot login, and I login as root and run the following commands:

[image: Virtualized guest]

When I try to run my hello program I am displayed the following message:

```
-sh: ./hello_world: not found
```

I suppose that my program is never executed, even if I have seen by debugging that it's loaded as an elf file into the system.

If I type an random command which doesn't exists, I get the same error.

The goal is to make the hello_world program run in user-space, on top of the kernel, I don't want it to be a part of it.

I agree with you guys, I'm probably missing some libraries or something basic, but I have no idea on what to do.

Comment: You should check for the execution-flag on the file. The default output-file is ./a.out, with -o, you change the output-file.

Comment: Where does `rootfs.ext2` come from? How are you compiling your "hello world" program? If you are building a dynamic binary, you would need to ensure that your virtual environment contains the same `ld.so` and other libraries as your build environment.  If you are building a static binary this would not be an issue.

Comment: `init` is the userspace program launched by the bare kernel.  You could replace it with anything you want.  In your case, you are launching `sh`, a shell.  When you try to run your program under the shell, it is telling you that you are not in the correct directory.

Comment: @stark, it's a bit confusing error message, I think larsks above is right, it's about libraries and loader.

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestions! I have modified the question in order to be more precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically run a process instead of init, if that is what you intend to do. To run a process instead of the systems init application, you can either replace the original init or pass *init=/path/to/you/application* as a kernel parameter to your VM.

But there are several things you should keep in mind:

All libraries need to be present in your VM at the same locations as on the system you have build the application on. This includes also the basic c-library it has been built against. You can get a list of all those libraries using

```
ldd hello_world
```

As an example, if you compile the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf("hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

you might get something like this as a result for ldd

```
$ ldd test
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdba6ba000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8559f50000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055fc58ece000)
```

If you replace the init process, you need to take care of console interrupts and handle them properly. If you don't you risk really bad system crashes. As a result, it is a good idea to keep an init process and let that process start your application, if you do not really know what you are up to.

I have seen the output of your command in the past. Are you using a shell-script to start your application? If so, it might indicate that you are currently missing some libraries in your virtual environment.

**Edit:**

Maybe you could instead create a statically linked application which means to compile all libraries into the same file. On gcc you could use that **-static** switch for that. See the difference:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c
$ ldd test
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcd1f22000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f088d43a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005580f8a2b000)
$ gcc -static -o test test.c
$ ldd test
    not a dynamic executable
```

As already mentioned you can use ldd to find the required libraries. Another option I would normally use is *objdump*, as the output is more detailed.

So for my application that would mean something like this (I have shortened the output to the relevant section):

```
$ objdump -p test

test:     file format elf64-x86-64

[...]

Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
  INIT                 0x00000000004003c8
  FINI                 0x00000000004005c4
  INIT_ARRAY           0x0000000000600e10
  INIT_ARRAYSZ         0x0000000000000008
  FINI_ARRAY           0x0000000000600e18
  FINI_ARRAYSZ         0x0000000000000008
[...]
```

So in my case, that is libc.so.6 I would need to copy from */lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6* on my host to */lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6* within the virtual machine.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes! I am using a shell-script to start Qemu. I think you are right about missing libraries, probably in the virtualized system I am missing everything since it works with the minimal kernel code and nothing else. Do you have any idea on how I can add those minimal features that would allow me to make my hello_program run? I have added more information to the question in order to be more precise

Comment: I have extended my answer. I would suggest you either use ldd or objdump or some other tool on your application to list the required libraries. Another (and probably easier) option is linking it statically.

Comment: I have recompiled my program with the -static flag and now it is run correctly on the guest machine. I have also checked inside the /lib folder in the guest machine and the required .so files in order to correctly run the program are missing.Thank you so much!